# How to "iterate" over submatrixes in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, braille

I have 36x80 Matrix in Matlab. 
It consists of 3x2 arrays which are the symbols of the Braille. i.e.

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 .....
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 .....
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 .....
.....................
```

Where first 3x2 submatrix represent "p" letter

```
0 0 
0 1
0 1
```

Next is "r" and so on.
And I have many of these "pattern" 3x2 matrixes which are represent Braille symbols.

How to translate that big matrix into matrix of English characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert this matrix to a cell array like:

```
Bs = mat2cell(B,repelem(3,size(B,1)/3),repelem(2,size(B,2)/2));
```

Where `B` is your original matrix.

You have to prepare the Braille code in the same manner, so you can compare it to your matrix:

```
letters = {'p',[0 0;0 1;0 1];'r',[0 1;0 0;0 1]}; % ...and so on for all letters
```

Then you can loop over `Bs`:

```
txt = char(zeros(size(Bs))); % the result
for k = 1:numel(Bs)
    for l = 1:size(letters,1)
        if isequal(Bs{k},letters{l,2})
            txt(k) = letters{l,1};
            break
        end
    end
end
```

And here is another option, without converting your matrix to cell array:

```
BB = reshape(reshape(B,3,[]),3,2,[]);
txt = char(zeros(size(B,1)/3,size(B,2)/2)); % the result
for k = 1:size(BB,3)
    for l = 1:size(letters,1)
        if isequal(BB(:,:,k),letters{l,2})
            txt(k) = letters{l,1};
            break
        end
    end
end
```

This should be faster, especially if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I wanted!